# Quiero hacer un menú con categorias y redireccionar hacia la pagina de productos con filtros usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, filtro, menu

como están?
Estoy haciendo una web con HTML, CSS, Javascript y un poco de PHP(solo para el formulario).
Mi problema viene al hacer un menú con categorías, en todas las secciones de la pagina, queriendo que al hacer click en alguna de ellas me redirija a la pagina de productos(donde están visualmente todos los productos) pero que automáticamente se filtre con dicha categoría y así aparezcan los productos correspondientes.

No me estaría saliendo la parte en la de reimprimir los productos que quiero es decir si redirijo bien pero al imprimir con el filtro no me estaria dejando.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu código? ¿Qué has intentado? Por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Te recomiendo además que completes el [tour] de bienvenida para conocer qué es un [mcve] y por qué es importante proveer de toda la información necesaria para reproducir tu problema/ escenario y poder ayudarte